# If b is a linear combination then Ax=b has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Q. True or False? If A = [a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>], where a<sub>j</sub> is the j<sup>th</sup> column of A, and if **b** is a linear combination of **a<sub>1</sub>** and **a<sub>3</sub>** then Ax=b has a solution.

I think its false because if b was a linear combination of only a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>3</sub> wouldn't that only be finding the solution to the matrix A = [a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>]?

Comment: No it's true; the criterion for  such a linear system to have solutions is that the augmented matrix has the same rank as $A$.

Comment: Look at the definitions! If $b$ is a linear combination of  $a_1$ and $a_3$ then it follows that $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$A x = A \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = x_1a_1 + x_2a_2 + x_3a_3 $$

If $b$ is a linear combination of $a_1$ and $a_3$, then it is also a linear combination of $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$, since

$$b = \lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_3 = \lambda_1 a_1 + \lambda_2 a_3 + 0 \cdot a_2 $$

This means that

$$x := \begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1\\0\\\lambda_2\end{bmatrix}$$
is a solution to

$$Ax = b $$